# Video player callback on a specific time

Tags: flutter, video-player

I would like to call a callback when the video arrives at a **specific** time.
If I understand correctly `cue points` and `metadata` are the most used terms for that.

I have added `betterPlayerController.addEventsListener` and filtering for `BetterPlayerEventType.progress` but it is not accurate, for example I have added print and this is the output (in milliseconds): `2611, 3209, 3809, 4413, 5020`

I have search bouth in [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) [API referenc](https://pub.dev/documentation/video_player/latest/) and [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) [documentation](https://jhomlala.github.io/betterplayer/#/README) and [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/better_player/latest/) but could not find that functionality.

I believe that it exists since it is the basic functionality of a video player.

Answer (score 0):

```
Duration myProgress;

_betterPlayerController.addEventsListener((event) => {
  if (event.betterPlayerEventType == BetterPlayerEventType.progress) {
    myProgress = event.parameters['progress']
    // HERE GIVE CALLBACK CONDITION
  },
}
```

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676308/cant-get-video-progress-time-in-flutter-better-player?rq=2) for similar question

Comment: This is what I am currently using (onProgress), I will update my question for that to be clearer.  This is not so accurate results as I have demonstrated and probably not very efficient.